# Query to find Table objects dependent on a Table in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I searched online to find a solution to the aforementioned topic but failed to get something that works for me. I only want a SQL statement that will query a database and bring out tables that are dependent on a particular table. I tried the `sp_depends` approach but it only brought out stored procedures and check constraints in the result set but no tables.

I stumbled on `sys.sql_expression_dependencies`but I discovered it doesn't work for SQL Server 2008. Please I need some help to get this done.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply we can do this  In SQL server management studio **Right-click on a table and choose 'View Dependencies'.**

By using query

```
Select
S.[name] as 'Dependent_Tables'
From
sys.objects S inner join sys.sysreferences R
on S.object_id = R.rkeyid
Where
S.[type] = 'U' AND
R.fkeyid = OBJECT_ID('tablename')
```

**Another method**

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, so.type 
FROM sys.objects AS so 
INNER JOIN sys.sql_expression_dependencies AS sed 
ON so.object_id = sed.referencing_id 
WHERE sed.referenced_id = OBJECT_ID('[tablename]');
```

Second method selects Procedures, views too.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. The first query worked for "Objects on which 'TableName' depends" but what I really want is the "Objects that depend on 'TableName' ". Because that is where I can get other tables that references the Table in question. I don't know if I am clear enough. Thank you so much. The second query doesn't work because sys.sql_expression_dependencies object doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way around it and I give the credit to **Arunprasanth KV** for giving a response that guided me to the solution. After studying the schema of the tables properly, the following query gave me exactly what I wanted:

```
Select
S.[name] 
From
sys.objects S inner join sys.sysreferences R
on S.object_id = R.fkeyid
Where
S.[type] = 'U' AND
R.rkeyid = OBJECT_ID('TableName')
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`dm_sql_referencing_entities`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630351.aspx) system view which will give you objects dependent on the `table`

```
SELECT referencing_schema_name,
       referencing_entity_name,
       referencing_id,
       referencing_class_desc
FROM   sys.Dm_sql_referencing_entities ('schema.Tablename', 'OBJECT')
```

Comment: Thanks for your respose, but dm_sql_referencing_entities doesn't work in SQL Server 2008, hence your answer cannot work for me.

Comment: @Kacey - No it should work in sql 2008. Did you read the link that i referred

Comment: Yes I looked up the link. I tried the query exactly the way you wrote it (replacing 'schema.Tablename' for 'dbo.Mytable') and it gives me this error: "Invalid object name 'sys.Dm_sql_referencing_entities' "